# If I am adding n data in recyclerview it is displaying n-1 data only.it is showing n th data when I add the n+1 th data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making a todo app where I have used a fab which on clicked opens a dialog which contains edit text.When user enters the data,I put it into the recyclerview dynamically using addnewdata() method. The problem is when user enters data, the previous entered data is shown in list and If I am adding n items it is showing only n-1 list. What should I do in this case?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewholder> {
    Context context;
    String EnterTitle, EnterDesc;
    private List<Todo> todolist;
    public CustomAdapter(List<Todo> todolist) {

        this.todolist = todolist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.tasktheme, parent, false);
        return new MyViewholder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewholder holder, int position) {
        Todo todo = todolist.get(position);
        holder.titletext.setText(todo.getTitle());
        holder.desctext.setText(todo.getDescription());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        System.out.println("The size of the recycler view adapter is ====================================" + todolist.size());
        return todolist.size();

    }

    public class MyViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView titletext, desctext;


        public MyViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titletext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            desctext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);

        }
    }
}
```

This is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddTaskDialog.DialogListner {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Todo> todolist = new ArrayList<>();
    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(todolist);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab=findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Floating Action Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                openDialog();

            }
        });
    addNewData("1 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("2 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("3 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("4 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("5 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("6 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("7 ", "Bhojani");
    addNewData("8 ", "Bhojani");
    }

    private void openDialog() {
        AddTaskDialog addDialog = new AddTaskDialog();
        addDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"example dialog");

    }

    private void addNewData(String Title, String Description) {
        Todo todo = new Todo(Title,Description);
        todolist.add(todo);
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void addListItem(String data_title, String data_Description) {
addNewData(data_title,data_Description);
    }
}


**This is my dialog classs**
public class AddTaskDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText Title,Description;
    private DialogListner listner;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);


        try {
            listner=(DialogListner) context;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException ex){
            throw  new ClassCastException(context.toString()+"must implement ExamplDialogListner");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialougr,null);
        Title= view.findViewById(R.id.et_title);
        Description=view.findViewById(R.id.et_description);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("New Task")
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                         String data_title=Title.getText().toString();
                         String data_description =Description.getText().toString();

                        listner.addListItem(data_title,data_description);
                    }
                });



    return builder.create();

    }

    public interface  DialogListner{

        void addListItem(String data_title,String data_Description);

    }
}
```

Comment: you should pass the new item to your adapter. after adding `todolist.add(todo);` some function in adapter and pass this todolist collection to adapter

Comment: I did what you said. I made a function in adapter class and passed the the recent item in todo list and then when I added new item in recyclerview using this method 'private void addNewData(String Title, String Description) { Todo todo = new Todo(Title,Description); todolist.add(todo); customAdapter.submitList(todolist); } ' but nothing changed. can you explain me what is the exact problem.

Comment: after passing did you call customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a function in your adapter as

```
fun submitList(itemList: List<Item>) {
    list = itemList
}
```

**list** here is the list of items declared at the top of your recycler view.Now call this function of your adapter from main and pass the list there

Comment: I did what you said. I made a function in adapter class and passed the the recent item in todo list and then when I added new item in recyclerview using this method         'private void addNewData(String Title, String Description) {
        Todo todo = new Todo(Title,Description);
                todolist.add(todo);
                customAdapter.submitList(todolist);
        } '  but nothing changed.  can you explain me what is the exact problem  @JoakimDanielson

Comment: did you call notifyDataSetChanged() in this function? sorry i missed it in answer

Comment: Thank you dear, I got my error solved.Actually there was some issue in my xml code.My recyclerview was going out of container.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Accepting the answer or by adding your answer describing how you solved the issue